# Hardware list for testing website layout

Tags: website-design, testing

I understand for testing websites that run cross-platform (iOS, iPadOS, MacOS, Android & Windows) and cross-browser (Chrome, Safari, Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera) that you're better off using physical hardware and not emulators.

When purchasing hardware for testing, is it important to have a device in different aspect ratios? For example; a current-gen iPhone 11 has an aspect ratio of 19.5:9, while iPhone X has an aspect ratio of 13:6.

Is there an up-to-date list of the necessary hardware for web development?

Comment: Apart from physical interaction, there's no difference in testing a website using an emulator versus a physical device

Comment: And i also don't think companies prefer to buy hardwares to test their products cross-browser. There're tools like namely StackBrowser to serve customers in that purpose and it's even a practice to automate this process.

Answer (score 1):

The more different devices, the better, that way you cover most common scenarios.

For stats on what resolutions to test, take a look at [StatCounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats) or DeviceAtlas, there you can get updated lists of most used screen resolutions worldwide.

For completeness: There are alternatives for testing on physical devices, services like Browserling and Saucelabs create a Virtual Machine that runs in your browser, for a quick test.